# How to intercept all submit() events via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story made very short, I'm working on a frontend where the main controls involve a great many individual `<form>` tags.

What I want is to intercept all submit() events, check the submitting form for a custom attribute, and if it's there, execute certain code.

I've got this:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var myForm=$(this);
    alert('SUBMIT!');
    if(myForm.hasOwnProperty('confirm')){
        alert ('Call confirmation');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(myForm.hasOwnProperty('verify')) {
        alert ('Call verification');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. The alert never triggers and neither does a breakpoint I set in the console.

I'm fairly new to JQuery and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myForm` is a jQuery object. You need to access the underlying DOM element to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var myForm = this; // Do not convert to a jQuery object here
    alert('SUBMIT!');
    if(myForm.hasOwnProperty('confirm')){
        alert ('Call confirmation');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(myForm.hasOwnProperty('verify')) {
        alert ('Call verification');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

FYI, jQuery has it's own method for checking for the existence of properties called [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), however personally I think `hasOwnProperty` is much nicer as it highlights what you are actually trying to achieve. Plus, you already have the DOM object by default and all browsers support the hasOwnProperty method so this has slightly less overhead than converting to a jQuery object.

Comment: That's good to know, and appreciated, but right now the entire function isn't triggering -- I'm not even getting the alert(). Once I've got *that* I'm fairly confident I'll be able to work out the rest...

Comment: You do have 3 alerts ;) Use `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) { ... });` and see if that works

Comment: The good news is that it worked for the submit. The *bad* news is that it seems to have overwritten a pair of onMouseOver() and onMouseOut() event I'd specified earlier in the code... Ah well.

Comment: But that's a different matter and I'll address it in a different question. Thanks!